# Are late registration / late entry poker tournaments the norm?

Tags: tournament, online

I want to play in a poker tournament that doesn't have a really elongated late registration phase. Is this a possibility online or is this pretty standard now - it's proving standard in my experience of 888 and Poker Stars.

I'm finding that tournaments end up being really elongated as more and more players pile in past the commencement time, and I'd prefer to play in something more time-limited. I'd be happy with a short late-registration period.

Comment: Why not just enter near the end of the late registration?

Answer (score 1):

Late registration can have very different effects on a tournament depending on the type of tournament that is being played. The starting stack size is the biggest factor in my experience, I have ran relatively deep in deep-stack tournaments after registering just before late registration ended.

The late registration is also the time when players in the tournament can rebuy if they bust early. This gives players multiple chances to run up a stack to have a bigger advantage after late registration is over.

**Pretty much all online MTTs have a late registration period**, it is up to you when you choose to register so experiment with different registration times and find what is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

Global Poker does not have Late registration on their MTTs if your in the US or Canada. Other than this site, the late reg thing is pretty common on the larger high traffic poker sites.
Some of the smaller less well known sites still offer a few freeze-out formats.